# Can a derivative change sign without crossing zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. If $f'(x)<0$ for all $x<0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, is it true that $f'(0)=0$ ? By Darboux's theorem, the left-hand limit or the right-hand limit of $f'$ should not exist here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know the intermediate value theorem for *continuous* functions, and we know that $f'$ need not be continuous. Surprisingly, however, the *conclusion* of the IVT holds also for derivatives! This is precisely what [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_%28analysis%29) says. The left- and/or right-hand side limit *may* fail to exist, but we still have that because of for example $f'(-1)<0<f(1)$, there must exist some $x$ with $-1<x<1$ and $f'(x)=0$. By the given conditions, the only candidate for such $x$ is $x=0$. Therefore $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Darboux's Theorem gives us that $f'(x)$ has the intermediate value property. For any $a<0$ and $b>0$, $f'(a)<0$ and $f'(b)>0$, so there must exist $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f'(x)=0$. We know that $x$ an be neither less than nor greater than zero, so $x=0$.